# Adjust value of v-text-field when using v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a v-card that contains a v-text-field that is populated using a v-model. The v-model that comes in is a time and it's showing HH:MM:SS, but I only want it to show HH:MM to the user. How do I format what is populated in the v-text-field?

I've tried using :input and various other change events, but none of them populate before the user clicks on the v-text-field, and I want it to be formatted as soon as they click the "Edit" card.

```
<v-text-field
  slot="activator"
  v-model="time.start"
  v-bind:label="$t('times.start')"
  prepend-icon="access_time"
  :rules="timeStartRules"
  @focus="$event.target.select()"
  required>
</v-text-field>
```

How do I format the "time.start" such that it's HH:MM instead of HH:MM:SS. Or, more generally, how do I call a function to modify the displayed text in the v-text-field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `computed` method.

Example :

```
<v-text-field
   slot="activator"
   v-model="formattedStartTime"
   v-bind:label="$t('times.start')"
   prepend-icon="access_time"
   :rules="timeStartRules"
   @focus="$event.target.select()"
   required
 ></v-text-field>
```

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      time: {
        start: '12:34:56'
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    formattedStartTime () {
      return this.time.start.substring(0,5);
    }
  }
}
```

Documentation : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Comment: Would filters work here as well given that there is a `v-bind:`? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html

Comment: As an update here, I needed to change the computed function in order to actually update the value when the user saves a new value.


`formatEndTime: {
      get: function(){
        return this.time.end.substring(0, 5);
      },
      set: function(value){
        this.time.end = value;
      }
    }`